# disable Rewriterule from 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've and oldsite with a lot of pages that I've converted to a new structure with WordPress.

I want to redirect old products to new products so I wrote a whole bunch of 301 redirect on the old server to the new one.

The redirection works but the rewriterule of the new server (set by wordpress) create a conflict. For exemple, if I request `oldsite.com/fabricationbarriereenfer/page1.html` I get `newsite.com/index.phpfabricationbarriereenfer/page1.html`

Here's the corresponding rule on the old server:

```
redirect 301 /fabricationbarriereenfer/page1.html http://www.newsite.com/projets/my-new-url
```

And here's the rewrite rule of WP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So is there a way to disable the rewriting if it come from a 301?
(and btw, is my rule well written?)

Comment: @anubhava it should be `newsite.com/projets/name-corresponding-to-old-project`

Comment: @anubhava the rules are on two separate server, the old one has 301's and the new has the rewrite

Comment: Hmm ok but WP is inly rewriting URLs internally, there is no external redirect on new site's .htaccess